# How do I get all of the attribute name of a specific product using the product id or sku?

Tags: product, product-attribute

I want to get all of the attributes for a specific product using its id or sku. This is my try:

```
$prod=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load(8536);
var_dump($prod->getAttributeText());
```

but i got this error message: **Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in...** What should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView(); 
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();

$productId = 52;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
 $product->setStoreId($storeId);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();


// get all attributes of a product
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {      
    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);   
    $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";    
}


//get only frontend attributes of a product
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);      
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";    
    }
}

// get name and value of particular attribute of a product
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {   
    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $code = 'color';
    if ($attributeCode == $code) {
        $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);   
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get all this data in backend, but if i not commented this line of code: $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);   it gives me in the firebug , 404. Am using to get all of this value an ajax . any ideea why it gives me the 404? the rest of it works fine, thx

Comment: you have to set store id for product might solve your issue.
 `$store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();`
`$storeId = $store->getStoreId();`
`$product->setStoreId($storeId);`

Comment: I put this code before the loop: $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView(); 
  $storeId = $store->getStoreId(); 
  $product->setStoreId($storeId); but still the same

Comment: try `$product->setStoreId($storeId);` after load product

Comment: please update your post with this

Answer (score 1):

```
$prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(8536);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($prod->getData());
```